# Triggering mailshot when new entry published - solutions?

Tags: entries

A client has a Campaign Monitor email list that he wants his new site to integrate with. We want to have a form that adds new subscribers to the list, and we also need to trigger a mailout to the list when a new blog post is published (not saved, but published on the site). He also wants the text of the blog post in the email that's sent out.

We are struggling to think of a solution that would work and can't find a plugin that would do the job. Sprout Email almost does it, but the Notifications part of that plugin doesn't hook into Campaign Monitor.

Anyone got any ideas for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find an existing plugin that has the functionality, you'll have the roll a custom one.

But knowing when an entry goes from pending to live is a [problem in and of itself](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/fire-event-first-time-future-dated-entry-goes-live-from-pending).

Assuming you got that sorted, the plugin would have to integrate with [Campaign Monitor API](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/) and send your email out to your list when the event happens.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think we are going to use RSS and hook it up that way with Campaign Monitor ([RSS to Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/rss-to-email/))