# Sprout Email trigger when entry goes live

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

In Sprout Email is it possible to set a notification trigger to be when an entry goes live?

I'd like to create entries ahead of time and post date them so that they go live on the specified date.  I'd like the Sprout Email notification to get triggered when the entry is live (rather than when it is saved).

Answer (score 1):

The docs state that the following events are available from Sprout Email:

- When a new entry is created
- When an existing entry is updated
- When a new user is created
- When a existing user is updated
- When a user is activated
- When a user is deleted
- When a user logs in

I think changing the status of an entry would trigger the "existing entry is updated". Not tested though.

Comment: Thanks @Jan_dh. I didn't think of trying the entry is updated trigger to see what happens when a post dated entry goes live. I came across a few threads stating that Craft in general doesn't send any events when a future post dated entry goes live so not sure if what I was hoping to do can be easily accomplished. Brad explains in more detail here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/fire-event-first-time-future-dated-entry-goes-live-from-pending . I'll give your suggestion a try and post back on what I find.

Comment: I tested @Jan_dh suggestion and the event to send email when an entry is updated is only triggered by resaving and entry and ignores the future post date feature.